# Dolphin emulator: Mouse cursor only works sometimes

Tags: mouse, super-mario-galaxy-2, dolphin-emulator

I have Super Mario Galaxy 2 in the Dolphin Emulator. Since I have to point for certain things and use the joystick on the nunchuck for general movement (and I don't have a USB sensor bar), I want to play with the nunchuck in my left hand and the computer mouse in my right hand, while the Wiimote just lies around (because I don't have a third hand).

I've set mouse up/down/left/right to move my cursor in the game up/down/left/right (I don't remember the name of the setting right now) and that works fine, except that it only does so sometimes. The in-game cursor appears and disappears seemingly randomly, sometimes for a second, sometimes for 10 minutes, sometimes until I restart the emulation or change the configuration of the controller and change it back.

Setup:
American version of Super Mario Galaxy 2 (SB401?)
Dolphin 5.0 (ac267a29405ae768037a8774b84b805a4180d1af)
Windows 7 Professional 64bit +SP1
[image]

How can I make the cursor reliable?

Comment: I believe your mouse is leaving the game screen area if that makes sense. You need to program Dolphin to respond to the movement of the mouse, not the location of the mouse cursor.

Comment: You mean IR up/down/left/right is not correct? What else should I choose? And no, it's not an issue of the mouse cursor leaving the game, because sometimes it stops working while the cursor is clearly in the middle of the screen and also I can move around the mouse wildly and it doesn't fix it.

Comment: What about the Height Center and Width values below that. You have them all at 50 - I saw a reddit thread while researching this that said to try and turn that values up. Not 100% sure what they do, but I think they will give you more "pick up" room

Comment: Can you search for a link?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/DolphinEmulator/comments/4vixsj/wii_mouse_pointer/

https://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/47kt6u/is_it_possible_to_use_a_mouse_in_dolphin_with_any/

Comment: That is not the problem I have. My in-game cursor is a bit offset from the mouse cursor, but it moves at the same speed (and I have just set it to hide the mouse cursor while in the game so that I'm not annoyed by this offset). The cursor does not leave the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [answer from one of the developers of Dolphin](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-mouse-cursor-only-works-sometimes?pid=457900) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180429222628/https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-mouse-cursor-only-works-sometimes?pid=457900)): This is a bug in the current version of Dolphin. It only affects hybrid Wiimote mode, emulated Wiimote mode works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind can you post your settings? It would make finding the problem a lot easier.

As for quick fixes, make sure you have hybrid Wiimote enabled, and disable every option apart from IR in the configuration. Do note that the motion controls  are actually a lot better in the earlier versions of Dolphin, in V3.0 it is much less buggy. V5.0 is fairly buggy in general when using the mouse as  motion controls, but the method described above gives the best results. I have V5.0 for Gamecube games and Wii games that don't involve motion controls (like Smash Brothers), and V3.0 for more motion control intensive games like Super Mario Galaxy. Hope this helps.

Comment: The setting is just plainly called "Cursor Y-", "Cursor Y+", "Cursor X-" and "Cursor X+" in the category "IR". I'll attach a picture with the configuration now.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough before: This answer didn't solve the problem for me.